# Sort Double Linked List

Tags: python, sorting, linked-list

I have to write a doubly linked list.
It is always sorted by price (in ascending order).

The list must be sorted by price with the addition of a new element.
The algorithm works, but if I change the price in the objects car1-5 or  add another object, it does not work anymore.

Code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price
class Node:
    def __init__(self, car):
    self.data = car
    self.nextNode = None
    self.prevNode = None
class LinkedList:
    head = None
    tail = None
    def addNode(self,car):
    new_node = Node(car)
    ref = self.head
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
        elif ref.prevNode is None:
            if int(new_node.data.price) < int(ref.data.price):
                self.head = ref.prevNode = new_node
                new_node.nextNode = ref
            if int(new_node.data.price)>int(ref.data.price) and     (new_node.data.price)>int(ref.nextNode.data.price):
                new_node.prevNode,  new_node.nextNode, ref.nextNode = ref,     ref.nextNode, new_node
        else:
            while ref is not None:
                if int(new_node.data.price) < int(ref.data.price):
                        if ref.prevNone is None:
                            self.head = new_node
                        else:
                            ref.prevNode.nextNode = new_node
                        ref.prevNode,new_node.prevNode = new_node, ref
                elif ref.nextNode is None:
                    self.tail = new_node
                    ref.nextNode, new_node.prevNode = new_node, ref
                    break
                else:
                    ref = ref.nextNode    
    def fromArray(self, cars):
        for item in cars:
            self.addNode(item)
def init(cars):
    L.fromArray(cars)
L = LinkedList()
car1 = Car(10)
car2 = Car(5)
car3 = Car(3)
car4 = Car(2)
car5 = Car(1)
 /*car6 = Car(33) */
cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4, car5,  /*car6*/]
init(cars)
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What is the smallest example which demonstrates the problem? What did you expect it to do? What did it do? Why do you think it should have done what you expected? What don't you understand about the output it did create?

Comment: I looked through the code execution http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.
For car 1-5 it is work.
But if i add some car6: <code>
    car1 = Car(10)
    car2 = Car(5)
    car3 = Car(3)
    car4 = Car(2)
    car5 = Car(1)
    car6 = Car(44)
    cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6] </code>
 It does not sorted correctly

Comment: I mean, what makes you say, *"this doesn't work"*?

Comment: Can you update the question with a full, simple, working failing example?

Comment: What's the problem with using a simple list and sorting it with some function after each 'insertion'? I don't get the need of previous and next node ¿links?

Comment: Previous and next node ¿links? were be necessary for other functions.

Comment: when price of any car is change , the code stops working